# Mac OS X pytest not recognized as a command

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pytest

There is a similar question to this, but its a bit out of date and concerns python 2.x, amongst other things.

Mac OS Catalina (10.15)

```
$ pip install -U pytest 
Collecting pytest
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/91/d68f68ce54cd3e8afa1ef73ea1ad44df2438521b64c0820e5fd9b9f13b7d/pytest-5.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: packaging in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest) (19.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: more-itertools>=4.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest) (7.2.0)
...
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from packaging->pytest) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: zipp>=0.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->pytest) (0.6.0)
Installing collected packages: pytest
  Found existing installation: pytest 5.1.1
    Uninstalling pytest-5.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pytest-5.1.1
Successfully installed pytest-5.2.1
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
$ ls -lat /usr/local/bin
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  26 root  wheel  832 18 Oct 07:09 .
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   84 18 Oct 07:09 pytest -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   19 18 Oct 07:04 pip -> /usr/local/bin/pip3
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel  192 12 Oct 20:18 ..
lrwxrwxr-x   1 root  admin   66  3 Oct 19:22 pip3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3
lrwxrwxr-x   1 root  admin   78  3 Oct 19:22 easy_install-3.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/easy_install-3.7
lrwxrwxr-x   1 root  admin   68  3 Oct 19:22 pip3.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   72  3 Oct 19:22 pyvenv-3.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pyvenv-3.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   68  3 Oct 19:22 pyvenv -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pyvenv
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   79  3 Oct 19:22 python3.7m-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   72  3 Oct 19:22 python3.7m -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   78  3 Oct 19:22 python3.7-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   71  3 Oct 19:22 python3.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   76  3 Oct 19:22 python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config
...
$ pytest --version
-bash: pytest: command not found
$ which pytest
$
```

I have skipped a bit of the output, but as you can see, pytest seems to be installed (according to their documentation), and has the right permissions, yet does not appear to be an executable command. I have even disabled the System Integrity Protection. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: The symlink `pytest -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest` is wrong - did you create it yourself? Either fix the symlink to point to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pytest`, or just add the dir to `PATH`, e.g. `export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"` in your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: ahhh...thankyou. Yes, I did create it myself, then tried to delete it with an `rm -rf`, but did not put the path on the file (so didn't actually delete it), so when I tried to put the correct link in, it was whinging that the file already existed, which I didn't notice.